# Share a folder without admin credential

Tags: active-directory, shared-folders

In our domain, users have "User" permission level, every time some user want to share a folder it will be prompt admin credential to finish, is there a way to allow domain users to freely share folders without administrator credentials?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are they having trouble creating the folder itself, or creating a share on an existing folder?  If they are trying to create a folder, exactly where are they trying to create it?  Do they have permissions to create folders in the location they are attempting to create it in?

Comment: sorry I updated the question.  I jut want to let them freely share files without admin right

Answer (score 0):

Creating shares is a computer-wide setting, and as such, regular users are not allowed to create shares.

You'll have to put the domain user's account into the Power Users permissions group on the computer(s) you want them to be able to make shares on.

Keep in mind this will give them other permissions on the computer, like being able to install software.